# Python- Sending a byte over UDP communication

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a single byte over UDP communication.

my client code:

```
import socket
msgFromClient="f"
bytesToSend=msgFromClient.encode()
UDPClientSocket =socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)
```

my server code:

```
server_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT_NO))

while True:
    adress,byte_message=server_socket.revfrom(1024)
    print (adress)
    print(byte_message)
```

and what i get:

```
b'f'
('192.168.4.15',55924)
```

each time i send it the integer in the tuple is different.
what i need is encode one letter to byte and decode it after receiving it.

Comment: You have switched `adress` and `byte_message`. And you get your `b'f'`, what's your problem?

Comment: oh i thought it was some kind of prefix,didnt realize it was encoded f thank you!

Comment: RTFM: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom. Quote: "The return value is a pair (bytes, address)" - not the other way around.